# include external simple node module in node-webkit

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I want to load external javascript node module in node-webkit. I want to add "unzip" module in my node-webkit application. I have added unzip module files in "node_modules" folder. and I included this file using
 `require('./node_modules/unzip.js');` 
But this is not working. I also tried this  `require('unzip.js');` 
but still it is not working. I have to do something else also to include module in my app?

Comment: `require('unzip');`. Assuming you've installed it with npm.

Comment: ok. can you please tell me how to install or add that module

Comment: `npm install --save unzip`.

Comment: thanks Ben its working. thanks for the help. I installed that module in my  node-webkit app so now it is working. :)